# How to iterate over a dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples called possible_moves containing possible moves on a board in my game:

```
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 5), (5, 2), (5, 3), (6, 0), (6, 2), (7, 1)]
```

Then, I have a dictionary that assigns a value to each cell on the game board:

```
{(0,0): 10000, (0,1): -3000, (0,2): 1000, (0,3): 800, etc.}
```

I want to iterate over all possible moves and find the move with the highest value.

```
my_value = 0
possible_moves = dict(possible_moves)
for move, value in moves_values:
    if move in possible_moves and possible_moves[move] > my_value:
        my_move = possible_moves[move]
        my_value = value
return my_move
```

The problem is in the part `for move, value`, because it creates two integer indexes, but I want the index `move` to be a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you don't even need the list of possible moves. The moves and their scores you care about are already contained in the dictionary.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> scores = {(0,0): 10000, (0,1): -3000, (0,2): 1000, (0,3): 800}
>>> max_move, max_score = max(scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
>>>
>>> max_move
(0, 0)
>>> max_score
10000
```

edit: turns out I did not understand quite correctly. Assuming that the list of moves, let's call it `possible_moves`, contains the moves possible right now and that the dictionary `scores` contains the scores for all moves, even the impossible ones, you can issue:

```
max_score, max_move = max((scores[move], move) for move in possible_moves)
```

... or if you don't need the score:

```
max_move = max(possible_moves, key=scores.get)
```

Comment: I need a list of possible moves, because I'm playing a game and I have to return the best move.

Comment: @Orbit09 yes, I meant that you don't need it for the task of finding the best move if you have a dictionary as shown.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I can find the best move in the dictionary using your hack, but then I still have to check if the found move is possible anyway.

Comment: @Orbit09 I think I understand now. It would have been easier if we had the full dictionary of scores. The edited answer should work for you, but I can't check the result because you truncated the dict in your question.

Comment: Great, it works perfect, thanks! If you want the full values dictionary, it is from the game Reversi: [https://www.google.cz/search?q=reversi+board+values&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGiMbd8-LeAhUphaYKHXL8DBUQ_AUIDigB&biw=1853&bih=950#imgrc=LYjO6jVNGoTNqM:]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max` with `dict.get`:

```
possible_moves = [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 5), (5, 2),
                  (5, 3), (6, 0), (6, 2), (7, 1), (0, 2), (0, 1)]

scores = {(0,0): 10000, (0,1): -3000, (0,2): 1000, (0,3): 800}

res = max(possible_moves, key=lambda x: scores.get(x, 0))  # (0, 2)
```

This assumes moves not found in your dictionary have a default score of `0`. If you can guarantee that every move is included as a key in your `scores` dictionary, you can simplify somewhat:

```
res = max(possible_moves, key=scores.__getitem__)
```

Note the syntax `[]` is syntactic sugar for `__getitem__`: if the key isn't found you'll meet `KeyError`.

Comment: As far as I understand the question now, the `0` is not necessary as a fallback value because `scores` is expected to contain all the fields of the board. If it does not, maybe `-1` or `float('-inf')` would be a better fallback value in case there can be zero-point moves. In any case, very similar to my last edit -> +1

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is a dict, iterator of `d` generates keys. `d.items()` generates key-value pairs. So:

```
for move, value in moves_values.items():
```

Answer (score 0):

```
possibleMoves=[(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 5), (5, 2),(0, 3),(5, 3), (6, 0), (6, 2), (7, 1),(0,2)]
movevalues={(0,0): 10000, (0,1): -3000, (0,2): 1000, (0,3): 800}
def func():
    my_value=0
    for i in range(len(possibleMoves)):
        for k,v in movevalues.items():
            if possibleMoves[i]==k and v>my_value:


                my_value=v
    return my_value
maxValue=func()
print(maxValue)
```